# How to read and sort a text file?

Tags: java

//    I used a java program to read a text file (athlete.txt) and outputs the contents to
the screen, I now need to write a java program that read and sort athlete.txt by Athlete number ( then prints its data on the screen. The output can be in ascending or descending order.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class AthleteRecords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("athlete.txt"));
        while (in.hasNextLine())
         {
           System.out.println(in.nextLine());
          }
      }
    }



    //Output file

    Athlete Number: 4233
    First Name: Peter
    Family Name: Brown
    Class 1 
    Position and points awarded for 100m race: 3  50
    Position and points awarded for 200m race: 2  80
    Position and points awarded for 400m race: 1  100
    Class 2
    Position and points awarded for 100m race: 3  50
    Position and points awarded for 200m race: 4  20
    Position and points awarded for 400m race: 2  80

    Athlete Number: 1235
    First Name: Robert
    Family Name: Anderson
    Class 1 
    Position and points awarded for 100m race: 4  20
    Position and points awarded for 200m race: 1  100
    Position and points awarded for 400m race: 2  80

    Class 2
    Position and points awarded for 100m race: 2  80
    Position and points awarded for 200m race: 1  100
    Position and points awarded for 400m race: 3  50

    Athlete Number: 3248
    First Name: Sean
    Family Name: Thompson
    Class 1 
    Position and points awarded for 100m race: 4  20
    Position and points awarded for 200m race: 1  100
    Position and points awarded for 400m race: 2  80
    Class 2
    Position and points awarded for 100m race: 2  80
    Position and points awarded for 200m race: 1  100
    Position and points awarded for 400m race: 3  50
```

Comment: Have you tried thinking of any ideas? You basically need to parse the file. Possibly putting them into objects as you read them, sorting them by Athlete Number (using Comparator interface), and then writing a toString method to get a string back for each athlete.

Comment: Can you actually try writing the code, then asking us for help with specific problems. We don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: Please specify the format of your input file and also the code you have written so far for sorting the athletes.

Comment: Looks like you might create an object Athlete that takes an athlete number and lets you add lines to the object (might be even better to parse the information).  Athlete looks like it should have fields: athleteNumber; firstName, lastName, ClassEvent[] array where a ClassEvent has number and Race[] array, and Race has distance, racenumber and points .. Then sort your list of Athletees (for bonus have a comparator for athlete number .. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'd create an `Athlete` class that holds all information you require, like this:

```
public class Athlete {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Race> class1Races;
    private List<Race> class2Races;

    public Athlete() {
        class1Races = new ArrayList<>(4);
        class2Races = new ArrayList<>(4);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //...probably more getters, if you need them elsewhere.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String idString = Integer.toString(id);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(60 + idString.length() + firstName.length() + lastName.length() + 52*class1Races.size() + 52*class2Races.size());
        result.append("Athlete Number: ");
        result.append(idString);
        result.append("\nFirst Name: ");
        result.append(firstName);
        result.append("\nFamily Name: ");
        result.append(lastName);
        result.append("\nClass1\n");
        for(Race race : class1Races) {
            result.append(race.toString());
            result.append("\n");
        }
        result.append("Class2\n");
        for(Race race : class2Races) {
            result.append(race.toString());
            result.append("\n");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    void addRaceClass1(Race race) {
        class1Races.add(race);
    }

    void addRaceClass2(Race race) {
        class2Races.add(race);
    }
}

public class Race { //And accompanying Race class to hold information about a race.
    private String name;
    private int position;
    private int points;

    public Race(String name,int position,int points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String positionString = Integer.toString(position);
        String pointsString = Integer.toString(points);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(42 + name.length() + positionString.length() + pointsString.length());
        result.append("Position and points awarded for ");
        result.append(name);
        result.append(" race: ");
        result.append(positionString);
        result.append("  ");
        result.append(pointsString);
        return result.toString();
    }

    //...probably some getters, if you need them elsewhere.
}
```

Next, you're going to need to parse that file. I don't know the complete file specification, but by your example I can guess:

```
private List<Athlete> parseAthletes(String filename) throws IOException {
    List<Athlete> result = new ArrayList<>(12);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    Athlete athlete = null;
    int currentClass = 0;
    String line = null; //Loop as long as there are input lines.
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //Sets the line variable and reads it all at once!
        if(line.startsWith("Athlete Number: ")) {
            athlete = new Athlete();
            result.add(athlete);
            athlete.setId(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(16))); //Throws NumberFormatException if not a number.
            currentClass = 0;
        } else if(line.startsWith("First Name: ")) {
            if(athlete == null) //No Athlete Number was seen yet.
                throw new IOException("Wrong format!");
            athlete.setFirstName(line.substring(12));
        } else if(line.startsWith("Family Name: ")) {
            if(athlete == null)
                throw new IOException("Wrong format!");
            athlete.setLastName(line.substring(13));
        } else if(line.startsWith("Class ")) {
            if(athlete == null)
                throw new IOException("Wrong format!");
            currentClass = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(6)); //Throws NumberFormatException if not a number.
        } else if(line.startsWith("Position and points awarded for ") && line.contains(" race: ")) {
            if(athlete == null || (currentClass != 1 && currentClass != 2))
                throw new IOException("Wrong format!"); //Need to have seen an athlete as well as a class number.
            String raceName = line.substring(32,line.indexOf(" race: ",32));
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(" race: ",32) + 7); //Trim off the start.
            int position = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,line.indexOf("  ")));
            int points = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf("  ") + 2));
            Race race = new Race(raceName,position,points);
            if(currentClass == 1)
                athlete.addRaceClass1(race);
            else //We already know class must be 2.
                athlete.addRaceClass2(race);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You might need to make a list of lists of races if the class number may be something else than just 1 and 2. It could also be made more efficient by caching the indexOf queries, but usually performance is not really an issue with these kinds of file parsers; you're way better off trying to make the reading be done in parallel and use a binary format, if this is a concern.

Lastly, to sort the list by ID, you can use a `Comparator`. You don't even need to create a whole new class for it, you can just define an instance of `Comparator` anonymously:

```
List<Athlete> athletes = parseAthletes("athlete.txt");
Comparator<Athlete> athletesById = new Comparator<Athlete>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Athlete a,Athlete b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.getId(),b.getId());
    }
}
Collections.sort(athletes,athletesById);
for(Athlete athlete : athletes) {
    System.out.println(athlete.toString());
}
```

This comparator defines that to compare two `Athlete`s, only the IDs need to be compared.

I may have made a typo here and there, or a logic error, so please test this code thoroughly, or better yet, be inspired by it and then write the code yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Ghostkeeper, I am very appreciative of the structure given, tremendous help! And yes, this is inspiring, Thanks.